# Can I filter a subset of the polygons without affecting the rest of the polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, filter

When using QGIS 3.10, I often filter out unneeded features to create my maps. Is there a way for me to filter a subset of the polygons without affecting the rest?

For example:
 The shapefile I have contains states and counties as of 1860. All of the polygons have a `STATE` attribute and a `COUNTY_TYPE` attribute. For South Carolina, I need to show polygons with `"COUNTY_TYPE" = 'District`,' but all other states need to show polygons with `"COUNTY_TYPE" = 'County'` (based on my data). I tried using an if/then operation in Query Builder, but this showed me only SC and eliminated the other states.

Can I filter the map to affect only SC while keeping the other states the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query builder, select first the condition for South Carolina, then for anything not South Carolina

```
(STATE= 'South Carolina' AND "COUNTY_TYPE" = 'District') 
OR (STATE != 'South Carolina' AND "COUNTY_TYPE" = 'County')
```

Answer (score 2):

Concat (use pipes: `||`) `"STATE"` and `"county"` for filter conditions:

```
"STATE" || "county" = 'South CarolinaDistrict' 
or ("STATE" || "county" LIKE '_County' AND "STATE" <> 'South Carolina')
```